# How to calculate difference from initial value for each group in R?

Tags: r

I have data arranged like this in R:

```
indv    time    val
A          6    5
A         10    10
A         12    7
B          8    4
B         10    3
B         15    9
```

For each individual (`indv`) at each time, I want to calculate the change in value (`val`) from the initial time.  So I would end up with something like this:

```
indv time   val val_1   val_change
A       6     5    5       0
A      10    10    5       5
A      12     7    5       2
B       8     4    4       0
B      10     3    4      -1
B      15     9    4       5
```

Can anyone tell me how I might do this?  I can use

```
ddply(df, .(indv), function(x)x[which.min(x$time), ])
```

to get a table like

```
indv    time    val
A          6    5   
B          8    4
```

However, I cannot figure out how to make a column `val_1` where the minimum values are matched up for each individual.  However, if I can do that, I should be able to add column `val_change` using something like:

```
df['val_change'] = df['val_1'] - df['val']
```

EDIT: two excellent methods were posted below, however both rely on my time column being sorted so that small time values are on top of high time values.  I'm not sure this will always be the case with my data.  (I know I can sort first in Excel, but I'm trying to avoid that.)  How could I deal with a case when the table appears like this:

```
indv    time    value
A          10   10
A           6   5
A          12   7
B           8   4
B          10   3
B          15   9
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's a plyr solution using `ddply`

```
ddply(df, .(indv), transform, 
      val_1 = val[1],
      change = (val - val[1]))

  indv time val val_1 change
1    A    6   5     5      0
2    A   10  10     5      5
3    A   12   7     5      2
4    B    8   4     4      0
5    B   10   3     4     -1
6    B   15   9     4      5
```

To get your second table try this:

```
ddply(df, .(indv), function(x) x[which.min(x$time), ])
  indv time val
1    A    6   5
2    B    8   4
```

## Edit 1

To deal with unsorted data, like the one you posted in your edit try the following

```
unsort <- read.table(text="indv    time    value
A          10   10
A           6   5
A          12   7
B           8   4
B          10   3
B          15   9", header=T)


do.call(rbind, lapply(split(unsort, unsort$indv), 
                  function(x) x[order(x$time), ]))
    indv time value
A.2    A    6     5
A.1    A   10    10
A.3    A   12     7
B.4    B    8     4
B.5    B   10     3
B.6    B   15     9
```

Now you can apply the procedure described above to this sorted dataframe

## Edit 2

A shorter way to sort your dataframe is using `sortBy` function from doBy package

```
library(doBy)
orderBy(~ indv + time, unsort)
  indv time value
2    A    6     5
1    A   10    10
3    A   12     7
4    B    8     4
5    B   10     3
6    B   15     9
```

## Edit 3

You can even sort your df using `ddply`

```
ddply(unsort, .(indv, time), sort)
  value time indv
1     5    6    A
2    10   10    A
3     7   12    A
4     4    8    B
5     3   10    B
6     9   15    B
```

Comment: Dear Jilber,  thanks so much for your help!  However, this would only work if the "time" column has values sorted from low to high.  I'm not sure if this is always the case in my data, although I could sort it first in Excel (which i'm trying to avoid using however).  Would there be a method when the values are not sorted, like in the following table:  indv time value
A 10 10
A 6 5
A 12 7
B 8 4
B 10 3
B 15 9

Comment: Dear Jilber, your edit seems to work great, thank you so much!  I had been trying all day to figure this out!  Now I will try it with my real data, thanks again for your help!!!

Comment: Glad to be useful. See my second edit for a shorter way to sort your data.frame.

Answer (score 5):

Here is a `data.table` solution that will be memory efficient as it is setting by reference within the data.table. Setting the key will sort by the key variables

```
library(data.table)
DT <- data.table(df)  
# set key to sort by indv then time
setkey(DT, indv, time)
DT[, c('val1','change') := list(val[1], val - val[1]),by = indv]
# And to show it works....
DT
##    indv time val val1 change
## 1:    A    6   5    5      0
## 2:    A   10  10    5      5
## 3:    A   12   7    5      2
## 4:    B    8   4    4      0
## 5:    B   10   3    4     -1
## 6:    B   15   9    4      5
```

Answer (score 4):

You can do this with the base functions. using your data

```
df <- read.table(text = "indv    time    val
A   6   5
A   10  10
A   12  7
B   8   4
B   10  3
B   15  9", header = TRUE)
```

We first `split()` `df` on the `indv` variable

```
sdf <- split(df, df$indv)
```

Next we transform each component of `sdf` adding in the `val_1` and `val_change` variables in a manner similar to how you suggest

```
sdf <- lapply(sdf, function(x) transform(x, val_1 = val[1],
                                         val_change = val - val[1]))
```

Finally we arrange for the individual components to be bound row wise into a single data frame:

```
df <- do.call(rbind, sdf)
df
```

Which gives:

```
R> df
    indv time val val_1 val_change
A.1    A    6   5     5          0
A.2    A   10  10     5          5
A.3    A   12   7     5          2
B.4    B    8   4     4          0
B.5    B   10   3     4         -1
B.6    B   15   9     4          5
```

### Edit

To address the sorting issue the OP raises in the comments, modify the `lapply()` call to include a sorting step prior to the `transform()`. For example:

```
sdf <- lapply(sdf, function(x) {
                     x <- x[order(x$time), ]
                     transform(x, val_1 = val[1],
                               val_change = val - val[1])
                   })
```

In use we have

```
## scramble `df`
df <- df[sample(nrow(df)), ]
## split
sdf <- split(df, df$indv)
## apply sort and transform
sdf <- lapply(sdf, function(x) {
                     x <- x[order(x$time), ]
                     transform(x, val_1 = val[1],
                               val_change = val - val[1])
                   })
## combine
df <- do.call(rbind, sdf)
```

which again gives:

```
R> df
    indv time val val_1 val_change
A.1    A    6   5     5          0
A.2    A   10  10     5          5
A.3    A   12   7     5          2
B.4    B    8   4     4          0
B.5    B   10   3     4         -1
B.6    B   15   9     4          5
```

Comment: Dear Gavin,  thanks for your help!  That method indeed works for my data, however only when the the time column is sorted so that the first values appear before the later values.  I'm not sure my data will always be sorted in that way.  Is there a similar method for when the times are out of order, like in the following table:  indv time value
A 10 10
A 6 5
A 12 7
B 8 4
B 10 3
B 15 9

Comment: Then sort `val` first or sort by `time` whichever it is that you want. It is much easier to sort the data frame first that to worry about handling it in the differencing operation.

Comment: I have suggested a solution to that. In future, it helps to formulate the question fully to avoid extended updating of answers etc. Hopefully the edit I made to my question helps?

Comment: Dear Gavin,  thanks.  Yes, the edit helps.  I'm sorry I didn't formulate the question fully, I didn't realize I had mis-formulated it until I read the answers.  I will try to be more careful next time!

Comment: How to perform the following operation like `val_1+val_change` with in the `lapply` function.And assign to the variable `new_val`.

Comment: @user7462639 Ask that as a a new question with a reproducible example