# How to apply function row-by-row into a data frame using dplyr without hardcoding the column names

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyverse

I have the following data frame:

```r
dat <- structure(list(setosa = c(50L, 0L, 0L), versicolor = c(0L, 11L, 
39L), virginica = c(0L, 36L, 14L)), .Names = c("setosa", "versicolor", 
"virginica"), row.names = c("1", "2", "3"), class = "data.frame")

dat
#>   setosa versicolor virginica
#> 1     50          0         0
#> 2      0         11        36
#> 3      0         39        14
```

This is the current code I use to calculate the score by hard-coding the column name into it:

```r
library(dplyrj)
dat %>% 
  rowwise() %>% 
  # here I hard code the column names into the score
  mutate(score = max(c(setosa,versicolor, virginica)/ sum(c(setosa, versicolor, virginica))))
```

Which produces:

```r
# A tibble: 3 x 4
  setosa versicolor virginica score
   <int>      <int>     <int> <dbl>
1     50          0         0 1.00 
2      0         11        36 0.766
3      0         39        14 0.736
```

What I want to do is to calculate each score, but without hard coded the column name.

How can achieve that?

Comment: A slightly more concise would be `do.call(pmax, dat)/rowSums(dat)`

Comment: @akrun how can I apply that to the dplyr pipe? To get the final result as in my OP.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A concise `base R` option would be

```
dat$score <- do.call(pmax, dat)/rowSums(dat)
```

---

In `tidyverse` we can do

```
library(tidyverse)
dat %>% 
    mutate(score = do.call(pmax, .)/reduce(., `+`))
#   setosa versicolor virginica     score
#1     50          0         0 1.0000000
#2      0         11        36 0.7659574
#3      0         39        14 0.7358491
```

Comment: .Is there any alternative function for `mutate` in `base R`

Comment: @user7462639  You can use `transform` i.e. `transform(dat, score = do.call(pmax, dat)/rowSums(dat))`

Comment: how can we solve this [commented function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13387245/how-to-calculate-difference-from-initial-value-for-each-group-in-r/13387371#comment85381731_13387371A) `sdf <- lapply(sdf, function(x) transform(x, val_1 = val[1],
                                         val_change = val - val[1]))`.

Comment: @user7462639  What is the issue with your command ? it works for me.  `lapply(sdf, transform, val_1 = val[1], val_change = val - val[1])`

Comment: Thank you for replay..  my intention is here `val_1` and `val_change` are temporary columns.

Comment: now again using those temporary columns i want create a another column.

Comment: @user7462639  In that case use `within` i.e. `lapply(sdf, function(x) within(x, {val_1 = val[1]; val_change = val - val_1}))`

Answer (score 1):

With the unquote splice operator `!!!`, you can do:

```
> library(tidyverse)
> psum <- function(...) reduce(list(...), `+` )
> mutate( dat, core = pmax(!!!syms(names(dat))) / psum(!!!syms(names(dat))) )
  setosa versicolor virginica      core
1     50          0         0 1.0000000
2      0         11        36 0.7659574
3      0         39        14 0.7358491
```

That works by generating the call for you, i.e.

```
> rlang::qq_show( mutate( dat, core = pmax(!!!syms(names(dat))) / psum(!!!syms(names(dat))) ) )
mutate(dat, core = pmax(setosa, versicolor, virginica) / 
                   psum(setosa, versicolor, virginica)
)
```